# how to fetch value from database and compare it in if condition

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to using the iPhone sqlite3 database. I want to fetch a value from a database and this value is checked in an if condition that is equal to some other value. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use sqlite directly unless you really really really have to.  If you don't want to use CoreData, use [the Flying Meat Database wrappers](http://flycode.googlecode.com) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sqlite directly unless you really really really have to.  Use CoreData.